# SchemaSpy providing Graphviz errors/warnings

Tags: graphviz, schemaspy

I am running SchemaSpy and am able to produce graphviz summaries, but receive two repeated errors/warnings. Here is a sample of the output from my run:

```
INFO  - Starting Main v6.2.2 on DESKTOP-43FMD5O with PID 17072 (C:\Users\TJF\Utils\SchemaSpy\schemaspy-6.2.2.jar started by TJF in C:\Users\TJF)
INFO  - The following profiles are active: default
INFO  - Found configuration file: C:\Users\TJF\Utils\SchemaSpy\config.file.txt
INFO  - Started Main in 1.595 seconds (JVM running for 2.174)
INFO  - Starting schema analysis
INFO  - Connected to Microsoft SQL Server - 12.00.5168
INFO  - Gathering schema details
Gathering schema details......(0sec)
Connecting relationships......(0sec)
Writing/graphing summary.INFO  - Gathered schema details in 0 seconds
INFO  - Writing/graphing summary
INFO  - Graphviz renderer set to ':cairo'
.ERROR - dot -Tpng:cairo relationships.real.compact.dot -orelationships.real.compact.png -Tcmapx: Warning: cell size too small for content
ERROR - dot -Tpng:cairo relationships.real.compact.dot -orelationships.real.compact.png -Tcmapx: Warning: cell size too small for content
ERROR - dot -Tpng:cairo relationships.real.compact.dot -orelationships.real.compact.png -Tcmapx: in label of node ValueEnumerationKey
```

The two messages I see repeatedly are:

- "Warning: cell size too small for content"
- "in label of node [tableName]"

I'm struggling to find documentation on how to resolve these issues and any help would be appreciated.

Haven't found any documentation to support these issues and unsure where to begin.

Answer (score 0):

I was struggling with the same thing.
The following may be helpful.

https://github.com/schemaspy/schemaspy/issues/833

Let's do our best for each other.